# Showing that an integral estimate is best possible

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

In this [paper](https://old.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1959-03.pdf), Paul Erdős shows that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k\cos(n_ix)\right| \ dx \le c\sqrt{k}
$$
for some constant $c$, where $0 < n_1 < \dots < n_k$ are integers and that this is the best estimate possible. In particular he shows that
for the sequence $n_i = i^2$, one has
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \left|\sum_{i=1}^k\cos(n_ix)\right| \ dx > ck^{\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon}
$$
The method he uses involves some number theoretic results and I find it quite technical. Is there potentially a different method to prove that $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{k})$ is the best possible estimate?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the right side of the second inequality supposed to be $cn_k^{1/2-\epsilon}$ instead of $ck^{1/2-\epsilon}$?

Comment: It's $k$, thanks for pointing out.